# Why is intensive mental activity so tiring if it just spends a bit more energy than in relax?

Tags: brain

As far as I know intense mental activity supposes spending about 1% more energy than what you would spend by basically making no real effort in any mental activity.

If that's the case, why is so tiring? In comparison a 1% extra activity from being quiet all day done with any other part of the body, would be way less tiring than that 1% extra activity from the brain.